# list index out of range IndexError at /en/dashboard/edit-server-request/2/

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

So i'm trting to edit a form and while submission it shows:
`IndexError at /en/dashboard/edit-server-request/2/ list index out of range`
this is the `views.py`

```
def edit_server_request(request, pk):
    server_request = get_object_or_404(ServerRequest, pk=pk)
    mediator = server_request.mediator
    teachers = server_request.teachers.all() if server_request.teachers.exists() else None

    TeacherFormSet = formset_factory(TeacherForm, extra=1, formset=BaseTeacherFormSet)

    if request.method == "POST":
        server_request_form = ServerRequestForm(request.POST, instance=server_request)
        mediator_form = MediatorForm(request.POST, instance=mediator)
        teacher_formset = TeacherFormSet(request.POST, prefix='form')

        if all([server_request_form.is_valid(), mediator_form.is_valid(), teacher_formset.is_valid()]):
            print('All forms are valid')
            server_request = server_request_form.save(commit=False)
            mediator = mediator_form.save()

            server_request.mediator = mediator
            server_request.user = request.user
            server_request.save()

            # Delete any existing teachers that were removed from the form
            existing_teachers = set(teachers)
            new_teachers = set()
            for form in teacher_formset.forms:
                teacher = form.save(commit=False)
                if teacher.name:
                    teacher.server = server_request
                    new_teachers.add(teacher)

            for teacher in existing_teachers - new_teachers:
                teacher.delete()

            # Save the new teachers
            for form in teacher_formset.forms:
                teacher = form.save(commit=False)
                if teacher.name:
                    teacher.server = server_request
                    teacher.save()
        else:
            print('One or more forms are invalid')

    else:
        server_request_form = ServerRequestForm(instance=server_request)
        mediator_form = MediatorForm(instance=mediator)
        initial_data = [{'name': teacher.name, 'contact': teacher.contact} for teacher in teachers] if teachers else None
        teacher_formset = TeacherFormSet(prefix='form', initial=initial_data)

    context = {
        'server_request_form': server_request_form,
        'mediator_form': mediator_form,
        'teacher_formset': teacher_formset,
    }
```

`forms.py`

```
class ServerRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Server request form for schools
    This uses a three way chained dependent dropdown for province, district and city
    """

    class Meta:
        model = ServerRequest
        fields = (
            'school_name', 'school_type', 'emis', 'phone', 'no_of_teachers', 'no_of_students',
            'no_of_laptops', 'no_of_desktops', 'internet_availability', 'province', 'district', 'city', 'ward', 'locale',
            'head_teacher_name', 'head_contact'
        )

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None) 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_id = user_id    

        self.fields['district'].queryset = District.objects.none()
        if 'province' in self.data:
            try:
                province_id = int(self.data.get('province'))
                self.fields['district'].queryset = District.objects.filter(province_id=province_id).order_by('name')
            except(ValueError,TypeError):
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty District queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['district'].queryset = self.instance.province.district_set.order_by('name')

        self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.none()
        if 'district' in self.data:
            try:
                district_id = int(self.data.get('district'))
                self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.filter(district_id=district_id).order_by('name')

            except(ValueError,TypeError):
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset

        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['city'].queryset = self.instance.district.city_set.order_by('name')

        self.fields['ward'].queryset = Ward.objects.none()
        if 'city' in self.data:
            try:
                city_id = int(self.data.get('city'))
                self.fields['ward'].queryset = Ward.objects.filter(city_id=city_id).order_by('name')
            except(ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['ward'].queryset = self.instance.city.ward_set.order_by('name')




class MediatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mediator
        fields = ('name', 'contact')

class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('name', 'contact')


class BaseTeacherFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        """
        Remove forms that have no name.
        """
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        forms = []
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE', False):
                forms.append(form)
        if len(forms) < 1:
            raise ValidationError('At least one teacher is required.')
        self.forms = forms
```

the template where the edit form is rendered:

```
<h1>{% trans 'Edit Server Request' %}</h1>
<form action="." method="post" id="server-request-form" 
    data-districts-url="{% url 'dashboard:ajax_load_districts' %}"
    data-cities-url="{% url 'dashboard:ajax_load_cities' %}"
    data-wards-url="{% url 'dashboard:ajax_load_wards' %}"
>
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ server_request_form | crispy }}

  <!-- {{ mediator_form | crispy }} -->

  {{ teacher_formset.management_form }}

  <!-- {% for form in teacher_formset.forms %}
      {{ form | crispy }}
  {% endfor %} -->
        {% for form in teacher_formset.forms %}
            <div class="row form-row spacer">
                <!-- <div class="col-2">
                    <label>{{ teacher.name.label }}</label>
                </div> -->
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{ form | crispy }} 
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
  {% if server_user.mediator %}

    <div class="mediator_fields" id="field1">
        {{ mediator_form | crispy }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if not server_user.mediator %}
    <label for="has_mediator">Are you a mediator filling this form on the behalf of School?</label>
    <select id="has_mediator" name="has_mediator">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no" selected>No</option>
    </select>
    <div class="mediator_fields" id="field1">
      {{ mediator_form | crispy }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
    <hr>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

while submission it shows the following traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/dashboard/edit-server-request/2/

Django Version: 1.11.4
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['jet',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.postgres.search',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'crispy_forms',
 'hitcount',
 'star_ratings',
 'analytical',
 'bootstrap_pagination',
 'admin_reorder',
 'django_cleanup',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'import_export',
 'captcha',
 'corsheaders',
 'pustakalaya_apps.core',
 'pustakalaya_apps.document',
 'pustakalaya_apps.collection',
 'pustakalaya_apps.audio',
 'pustakalaya_apps.video',
 'pustakalaya_apps.image',
 'pustakalaya_apps.other',
 'pustakalaya_apps.dashboard',
 'pustakalaya_apps.pustakalaya_analytics',
 'pustakalaya_apps.pustakalaya_search',
 'pustakalaya_apps.pustakalaya_account',
 'pustakalaya_apps.review_system',
 'pustakalaya_apps.favourite_collection',
 'pustakalaya_apps.show_featured',
 'pustakalaya_apps.set_featured',
 'pustakalaya_apps.software_downloads',
 'pustakalaya_apps.interactive',
 'pustakalaya_apps.accessibility',
 'pustakalaya_apps.epub_reader',
 'pustakalaya_apps.school']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder']



Traceback:

File "C:\olen\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\olen\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\olen\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\olen\olen-elib\src\pustakalaya_apps\dashboard\school_views.py" in edit_server_request
  188.         if all([server_request_form.is_valid(), mediator_form.is_valid(), teacher_formset.is_valid()]):

File "C:\olen\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in is_valid
  323.             form = self.forms[i]

Exception Type: IndexError at /en/dashboard/edit-server-request/2/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Comment: You should consider upgrading your Django version

Comment: I think that your validation logic in `BaseTeacherFormset` is wrong. Probably you don't even need to implement that. To validate the minimum number of forms submitted you can use `validate_min` kwarg when using the `formset_factory`. See more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/#validate-min